# Detail work in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I have some very detailed artwork which I drew by hand on pen and paper but I'm looking to turn them into a vector.

I have already done the live trace but it doesn't pick up all the tiny dots which make up the shading.

Do any of you know a better way I could do this so that it picks up all the detail or a way to apply the effect in illustrator or any other program?

[image: Feather]

Comment: Did you try adjusting the tracing options? What "effect" are you referring to? I'm afraid a sample image may be needed. Also, if you are asking about Illustrator, please don't tag your question with the Photoshop tag.

Comment: There is part of the drawing a yes I have tried that it ether makes it to black or to white with not enough detail. and by effect I mean the dot work. and that was in case there was a solution within photoshop

Answer (score 1):

There is no effect which is going to mimic that sample.

You can try:

- Adjusting the settings for image trace
- Scan the original at a higher resolution
- Enlarge the original when you scan it (tracing a larger image will pick up more detail because the detail will be larger).
- Manually add the areas which are not being traced well.